# How do I modify pd.DataFrame using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I got a problem with iterative modification of dataframe (**h0**). I need to replace strings in my dataframe, and I have a list of strings which should be replaced (two columns: first for string that should be replaced, second for string which should go to the dataframe as new value - it is the **zv** dataframe).

I want to replace 584 different strings in my dataframe, therefore I am trying to use a `for` loop.

I've tried this:

```
h0 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('C:/blablabla/vyberhp.csv', delimiter=';'))

zv = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('C:/blablabla/vycuc2.csv', delimiter=';'))

zv_dlzka = len(zv.index)

for i in range(zv_dlzka):
    h1 = h0.replace(zv.at[i, 'stary_kod'], zv.at[i,'kod'], regex=True)

print(h1)
```

The result is that I see only last iteration (so replaced only string from last row from my list for string replacement).

I know where the problem is. It's here:

```
h1 = h0.replace(zv.at[i, 'stary_kod'], zv.at[i,'kod'], regex=True)
```

because for cycle always calls the first DataFrame (h0), but I have no idea how to fix it.

What are the ways to make the for loop work with modified DataFrames (so not h0) in each iteration?

Sorry if this is a basic question, I am quite new to coding.

Comment: `h0 = h0.replace(...)`

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title and sentences. This would be gentle to your readers.

Comment: Sorry for mistakes and thank you for your fast reply!

Comment: Please explain using sample data what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Interesting solution to your problem! It should work but reason why your only seeing the last change is because your overwriting the h1 variable on every loop till the last one. If you change h1 to h0 it should work